# Why dialog not show if I setParent?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I create a dialog, and If I set mainwindow as it's parent, it not show.If I comment  `dlg.setParent(QApplication.activeWindow())`,It work well, It's that dialog couldn't set mainwindows as it's parent?

```py
from qtpy.QtWidgets import *
from qtpy.QtGui import *
from qtpy.QtCore import *

def center(w: QWidget):
    top = QApplication.activeWindow()

    rect = QRect(top.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, 0)), top.size())
    r = QStyle.alignedRect(Qt.LeftToRight, Qt.AlignCenter, w.size(), rect)
    w.move(r.topLeft())

class Button(QPushButton):
    def mousePressEvent(self, e: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        super().mousePressEvent(e)
        dlg = QDialog()
        dlg.resize(100, 100)
        dlg.setParent(QApplication.activeWindow())
        # center(dlg)
        dlg.exec()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setCentralWidget(Button())

app = QApplication([])
main = MainWindow()
main.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: `dlg = QDialog(QApplication.activeWindow())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Qt documentation:

> A dialog is always a top-level widget, but if it has a parent, its default location is centered on top of the parent's top-level widget (if it is not top-level itself). It will also share the parent's taskbar entry.

> Use the overload of the QWidget::setParent() function to change the ownership of a QDialog widget. This function allows you to explicitly set the window flags of the reparented widget; using the overloaded function will clear the window flags specifying the window-system properties for the widget (in particular it will reset the Qt::Dialog flag).

The `setParent` method it takes two arguments, the second being the window flags, so leaving out the second argument leaves you with a qdialog with no window flag.  In order do show the dialog again, just reassign the window flags.

Comment: In my mind, I always thinks there is  only one fucntion `setParent `.You had tell me now.

Comment: @jie As opposite to Python, C++ allows function overloads, multiple functions that have the same "name" but do different things based on their argument signature. Always look for the documentation in order to understand the differences (and check the inherited classes too); QWidget has *two* `setParent()`: the [default](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setParent) that only takes the parent widget (similarly to QObject `setParent()`) and clears the flags except for the titlebar buttons, and the [*overloaded*](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setParent-1) one that also accepts window flags.

Comment: @jie as suggested by the comment from ekhumoro, you should just create the dialog instance with the parent argument instead. It's simpler, and more appropriate.

Comment: @musicamante yes,you are right, I just forgot it,no matter danger way or light way, that all I want to try.

Comment: @jie There's nothing wrong in *trying*: on the contrary, you should be *eager* to try, as that's an incredible source of learning. Just remember that you shall always look for the documentation (and, in the case of Qt, it is usually comprehensive and very well written), which means that you shall always remember to also look up for the documentation of inherited classes. Have fun, experiment, and prove yourself wrong whenever you have doubts (and even if you don't) :-)